# Unable to generatechangelog or diffChangeLog for data using Liquibase for PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

The generated log file has only the create command.

I tried using :

```
./liquibase generateChangeLog --diffTypes="data"
```

But did not work. No insert commands were present in the changelog

I am using Liquibase 3.5.3 and PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: I found the solution: 

need to create a directory and use the command:
./liquibase --diffTypes="data" --dataOutputDirectory="/pgdb/lb/insert" generateChangeLog

Comment: Did it generate a changelog file and insert the data as csv files in that directory or did it just insert the data in the directory? Because in my case it just puts the data as csv files in the directory while I need the changelog file too.